# Correct Positioning of Stamp PDF Over Words in Original PDF using pypdf and ReportLab

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, pdfplumber

I'm currently working on a Python project that involves processing PDF files. My objective is to identify specific words from a predefined list within a text-based PDF and overlay a stamp PDF onto the original PDF to highlight these words. I've encountered difficulties in ensuring that the stamp PDF is positioned accurately over the identified words.

Here's a breakdown of my process:

I'm using the PdfReader class from pypdf to extract text from the original PDF.
To locate the words and create the stamp PDF, I'm utilizing several tools including pypdf, pdfplumber, reportlab, and its canvas and letter modules.
I've developed a function add_stamp_to_pdf that is responsible for overlaying the stamp PDF onto the original PDF. The function utilizes the PdfReader and PdfWriter classes from the pypdf library.

```
from pypdf import PdfWriter, PdfReader

def add_stamp_to_pdf(pdf_file, stamp_pdf_path, output_path):
    pdf = PdfReader(pdf_file)
    stamp_pdf = PdfReader(stamp_pdf_path)
    
    writer = PdfWriter()
    
    for page_num in range(len(pdf.pages)):
        page = pdf.pages[page_num]
        stamp = stamp_pdf.pages[page_num]
        
        page.merge_page(stamp, over=False)  # Set to False for watermarking
        writer.add_page(page)
        
    with open(output_path, "wb") as output_file:
        writer.write(output_file)

output_pdf = path
file_path = path
add_stamp_to_pdf(file_path, stamp_pdf_path, output_pdf)
```

Despite my efforts, I'm experiencing issues with the positioning of the stamp PDF over the words I've identified. The alignment is often off, and the stamp doesn't match the exact locations of the identified words. I've double-checked my code, but I'm struggling to identify where the problem might be originating.

If anyone has encountered similar challenges when using pypdf, pdfplumber, and reportlab to overlay stamp PDFs onto specific words within a text-based PDF, I would greatly appreciate any insights or advice. Particularly, if there are specific considerations when translating positions from text-based coordinates to PDF page coordinates, or if there are recommendations for refining the stamp creation process using reportlab, please share your expertise.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: You wrote PyPDF2, but imported from `pypdf`. Hence I replaced it by "pypdf" everywhere.